# Separate css rules for dividers of one splitPane

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have the following css class in css file

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {  
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;  
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

And I have a splitPane with two dividers and I have reference to these dividers as Node(!). I mean

```
Node leftDivider;
Node rightDivider;
```

I get reference to them this way

```
List<Node> nodes=getDividerNodes(splitPane);
leftDivider=nodes.get(0);
rightDivider=nodes.get(1);

...
public static List<Node> getDividerNodes(SplitPane splitPane){
    Map<Double,Node> sortedMap=new TreeMap<>();
    if (splitPane.getOrientation()==Orientation.HORIZONTAL){
        splitPane.lookupAll(".split-pane-divider").stream().forEach(div ->  {
            if (div.getParent()==splitPane){
                sortedMap.put(div.getLayoutX(), div);
            }
        });
    }else{
        splitPane.lookupAll(".split-pane-divider").stream().forEach(div ->  {
            if (div.getParent()==splitPane){
                sortedMap.put(div.getLayoutY(), div);
            }
        });
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(sortedMap.values());
}
```

Now I wan't to display leftDivider but not to display rightDivider. I do

```
leftDivider.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 5 0 0;");
```

However, I see both dividers - left and right. Besides, if I want to see only right divider and I do

```
rightDivider.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 5 0 0;");
```

I don't see any dividers.

It seems to me that separate control of dividers inside one splitPane is not possible. If I wrong, please, say how can I show only one of two dividers?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are getting the references to the dividers?

Comment: @James_D I posted code.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. In particular, the [`SplitPaneSkin`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/SplitPaneSkin.java) class contains the following method:

```
private void layoutDividersAndContent(double width, double height) {
    final double paddingX = snappedLeftInset();
    final double paddingY = snappedTopInset();
    final double dividerWidth = contentDividers.isEmpty() ? 0 : contentDividers.get(0).prefWidth(-1);

    for (Content c: contentRegions) {
//        System.out.println("LAYOUT " + c.getId() + " PANELS X " + c.getX() + " Y " + c.getY() + " W " + (horizontal ? c.getArea() : width) + " H " + (horizontal ? height : c.getArea()));
        if (horizontal) {
            c.setClipSize(c.getArea(), height);
            layoutInArea(c, c.getX() + paddingX, c.getY() + paddingY, c.getArea(), height,
                0/*baseline*/,HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        } else {
            c.setClipSize(width, c.getArea());
            layoutInArea(c, c.getX() + paddingX, c.getY() + paddingY, width, c.getArea(),
                0/*baseline*/,HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
    for (ContentDivider c: contentDividers) {
//        System.out.println("LAYOUT DIVIDERS X " + c.getX() + " Y " + c.getY() + " W " + (horizontal ? dividerWidth : width) + " H " + (horizontal ? height : dividerWidth));
        if (horizontal) {
            c.resize(dividerWidth, height);
            positionInArea(c, c.getX() + paddingX, c.getY() + paddingY, dividerWidth, height,
                /*baseline ignored*/0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        } else {
            c.resize(width, dividerWidth);                
            positionInArea(c, c.getX() + paddingX, c.getY() + paddingY, width, dividerWidth,
                /*baseline ignored*/0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `dividerWidth` is computed for a single divider, and the same value is used in the layout of all dividers. Consequently all dividers are the same size, irrespective of the different styles they may each have.

I recommend you search to see if this is already reported (I did a [quick search](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8114111?jql=text%20~%20%22splitpane%22) and didn't find anything), and report it if not.

Comment: Unfortunately can't find a way how to register. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Pavel You can submit bugs [here](http://bugs.java.com/) without a project role (though you still need Oracle registration: you should see a link to create an account if you don't have one).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.